# Problems with Unslider and HTML's Nav

Tags: html, css, unslider

I'm really perplexed in this situation. I used the Unslider slider and I got it working fine, until now. One of the problems with the slider are the photos involved. The first photo will be shown by default as first, but I can't slide to the next photo as the second photo is located right below the first. So to say there are multiple photos per slide. The next slide shows blank.

Also another thing is that my navigation text isn't allowing me to go to another .html page, despite me listing down the  tag for each navigation option.

Codes

```css
.photo {
  width: 800px;
  height: 500px;
}
.my-slider {
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  right: 11em;
  bottom: 1em;
  width: 800px;
  height: 500px;
}
/* Slider */

.unslider {
  overflow: auto;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 30px;
  position: relative;
}
.unslider-wrap {
  position: relative
}
.unslider-wrap .unslider-carousel>li {
  float: right
}
.unslider-vertical>ul {
  height: 100%
}
.unslider-fade {
  position: relative
}
.unslider-fade .unslider-wrap li {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 8
}
.unslider-fade .unslider-wrap li .unslider-active {
  z-index: 10
}
.unslider li,
.unslider ol,
.unslider ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
}
.unslider-arrow {
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  z-index: 2;
  cursor: pointer;
  clear: both;
}
.unslider-arrow.next {
  top: 33em;
  left: 56em;
  right: 20px;
}
.unslider-arrow.prev {
  top: 33em;
  left: 41em;
}
/* Slider Navigation */

.unslider-nav ol {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  left: 33.5em;
  bottom: 1em;
}
.unslider-nav ol li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 6px;
  height: 6px;
  margin: 0 4px;
  background: transparent;
  border-radius: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-indent: -999em;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.unslider-nav ol li.unslider-active {
  background: #fff;
  cursor: default;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/unslider/2.0.3/css/unslider.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/unslider/2.0.3/js/unslider-min.js"></script>

<body>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <a href="index.html">
        <li>Home</li>
      </a>
      <a href="portfolio.html">
        <li>Portfolio</li>
      </a>
      <a href="gallery.html">
        <li>Gallery</li>
      </a>
      <a href="contact.html">
        <li>Contact</li>
      </a>
      <a href="feedback.html">
        <li>Feedback</li>
      </a>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <div class="my-slider unslider-horizontal">
    <ul class="unslider-wrap unslider-carousel">
      <li class="unslider-active">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-800-500-3.jpg" alt="Shadowed (2015)" class="photo">
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-800-500-3.jpg" alt="Shaped (2015)" class="photo">
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="unslider.js"></script>
  <script src="//stephband.info/jquery.event.move/js/jquery.event.move.js"></script>
  <script src="//stephband.info/jquery.event.swipe/js/jquery.event.swipe.js"></script>

  <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
      $('.my-slider').unslider({});
    });
  </script>
  <script>
    $('.infinite-slider').unslider({
      infinite: true
    });
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Kindly provide a working fiddle so I can understand the problem better and give you the exact solution.

Comment: I fixed your snippet. Please combine all of your code into one snippet and load external files like unslider js and css. From what I see it's working just fine. Do you have this hosted online so that we can see the issue you're having?

Comment: I found out the solutions to both of my problems for now. It seems my .unslider is blocking out the HTML links, making them unclickable. For the slider itself, I accidentally seperated 2 classes from each othe, hence rendering it useless. Just some disarranged code that's all. Thanks for your help anyways.